# Error compiling in release mode but not in debug mode

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, crypto++

When I compile on VS 2008 in deubg mode everything works fine.
When I compile the same thing in release mode not everything works.  As far as I can tell the include directories are the same and there are no additional preprocessor symbols.

Any help?

> 1>zlib.cpp 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\include\xutility(419) : error C2664:
>   'CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup::AllocatorWithCleanup(const
>   CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup &)'
>   : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup' to
>   'const
>   CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup &'
>   1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   T=std::_Aux_cont 1>        ] 1>
>   and 1>        [ 1>
>   T=CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo
>   1>        ] 1>        and 1>        [
>   1>            T=std::_Aux_cont 1>
>   ] 1>        Reason: cannot convert
>   from
>   'CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup' to
>   'const
>   CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup' 1> 
>   with 1>        [ 1>
>   T=CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo
>   1>        ] 1>        and 1>        [
>   1>            T=std::_Aux_cont 1>
>   ] 1>        No user-defined-conversion
>   operator available that can perform
>   this conversion, or the operator
>   cannot be called 1>        C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\include\xutility(417) : while compiling class template member
>   function
>   'std::_Container_base_aux_alloc_real<_Alloc>::_Container_base_aux_alloc_real(_Alloc)'
>   1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   _Alloc=CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup
>   1>        ] 1>        C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\include\vector(421) : see reference to class template
>   instantiation
>   'std::_Container_base_aux_alloc_real<_Alloc>'
>   being compiled 1>        with 1>
>   [ 1>
>   _Alloc=CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup
>   1>        ] 1>        C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\include\vector(439) : see reference to class template
>   instantiation
>   'std::_Vector_val<_Ty,_Alloc>' being
>   compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>
>   _Ty=CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo,
>   1>
>   _Alloc=CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup
>   1>        ] 1>
>   C:\myproject\sshlib\zinflate.h(79) :
>   see reference to class template
>   instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty,_Ax>'
>   being compiled 1>        with 1>
>   [ 1>
>   _Ty=CryptoPP::HuffmanDecoder::CodeInfo,
>   1>
>   _Ax=CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup
>   1>        ] 1>zinflate.cpp

The line of code it eventually points to is:

```
std::vector<CodeInfo, AllocatorWithCleanup<CodeInfo> > m_codeToValue;
```

**Edit: More info:**

I get this error exactly when my preprocessor contains NDEBUG instead of _DEBUG. If I change my release config to have _DEBUG isntead it compiles.  Why?

Comment: Looks like a const-ness problem with the allocator parameter on your vector. Do you have more code?

Comment: #defining `_DEBUG` basically switches the build to debug mode. The custom allocator strategy of the Microsoft STL is different in debug mode, and is not affected by the bug. See the Nabble link in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in the Visual C++ compiler. See [http://old.nabble.com/-jira--Created:-%28QPID-1458%29-C%2B%2B-common-compile-error-in-VC9-Release-mode-td20469700.html](http://old.nabble.com/-jira--Created%3a-%28QPID-1458%29-C%2B%2B-common-compile-error-in-VC9-Release-mode-td20469700.html).

You can work around it by disabling [checked iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

```
#define _SECURE_SCL 0
```

But be warned: if you link against a third-party library that was compiled with `_SECURE_SCL` enabled, like e.g. [boost](http://www.boost.org/), memory corruption can (and will) occur.

Comment: I am pretty sure I used to have this error, and it went away... after installing a Visual Studio service pack, perhaps? We do work with boost.

Comment: Interesting. @MS SQL Server, can you provide the exact version of your compiler?

Comment: It's the base VS2008 install.  I am hoping this is the solution.  I'm trying first by applygin 2008 SP1 to see if that works.  I'll update the ticket when the install is finished.

Comment: The flag worked like a charm but I do use boost but it is linked separately, so I'm a little scared. The SP1 itself did nothing to fix the problem.  Do I have any other options?

Comment: Try installing all the updates from [http://update.microsoft.com/](http://update.microsoft.com/). Reboot your machine. Enable checked iterators. Take a deep breath. Rebuild your solution. Keep us posted :)

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to C++ after many years, I encountered a similar error. Turned out it had nothing to do with this bug and everything to do with the fact that I hadn't updated my Release configuration to the same settings as used in the Debug configuration! So for the other noobs out there -- remember to make sure that you have the same Character Sets, CLR Support, Include Directories, Additional Dependencies, and so forth in all your configurations.